# Ipad-Data not showing on UItableview

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I am developing an ipad app.In this app,I have two sections-one showing a Gallery like grid view and other a tableview.
My gridview worked successfully.

When I implemented the tableview,it **goes full screen** with specified row height and bgcolor.But the **data is not shown on the tableview**.I am collecting the data from plist.

I designed the tableviewcell to display each row in style.But the tableviewcell design is not working in tableview.

I used some codes from **Advancedtableviews sample program by Apple.**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"categoryCell";

    categoryCell *cell = (categoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    // Configure the data for the cell.
    NSDictionary *dataItem = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:[dataItem objectForKey:@"Icon"]];

    cell.name = [dataItem objectForKey:@"Name"];

    cell.num = [dataItem objectForKey:@"Num"];

    return cell;
}
```

How could I overcome the problem?

Comment: Did you set the delegate and the data source?

Comment: @CodaFi Yes,I set the delegate and data source

Comment: You need to show that you've taken some steps to attempt to fix the problem yourself as well as share relevant sample code, such as your implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I as well as others will flag any questions for moderation if they do not meet posting guidelines.

Comment: Are you using storyboards and prototype cells? If not, you are not creating your cells.

Comment: @jrturton I'm using prototype cells

Comment: Add some breakpoints. I'll bet that the above method is not being called because you are returning 0 for your number of sections or your number of rows in a section.

Comment: @jrturton Thanks.I got 'null' from the return of number of rows in a section.

Comment: Has that solved it? Should I add my comment as an answer?

Comment: @jrturton Yes,the problem is solved.You can add the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a breakpoint to your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. If the method is never called, then there is an issue in your other data source methods - you will be returning 0 for the number of sections in the table, or the number of rows in a section.